# Proving a constraint on $n$ when $n$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that $n$ ($18 \leq n \leq 400$ and $n\neq 361$) is prime if and only if $n$ does not have proper factor $2$ or $5$ and $\gcd(n,51051) = 1$.

I'm not sure how to start but realised that $51051$ is a product of $3,7,11,13,17$ which are some of the primes in that interval?

Comment: What about $19^2=361$?

Comment: Actually it must be $$\gcd(n,969969)=1$$where $$969969=3\times7\times11\times13\times17\times19$$

Comment: Sorry  I forgot to mention that $n \neq 361$.

Comment: What about $n=3,7,11,13,17$?  All of these are primes, but $\gcd(n,51051)\neq1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove that an integer $\ N>1\ $ is prime, it is sufficient to show that it has no prime factor upto $\ \lfloor \sqrt{N} \rfloor\ $.

Hence , for integers in the range $\ [18,400]\ $ , we only need to check the primes upto $\ 19\ $.

Moreover, the only composite with no prime factor smaller than $\ 17\ $ in this range is $\ 19^2\ $ (I leave it as an exercise to show this) , hence the two conditions are sufficient, if we consider the exception $\ 361\ $

On the other hand, if one of the conditions does not hold, we must have a factor in the range $\ [2,17]\ $, hence $\ N\ $ cannot be prime.